# Adding element to array in powershell scriptblock converts array to string

Tags: arrays, powershell, scriptblock

I noticed odd behaviour using arrays in scriptblocks. The following code shows the problem:

```
$array = @("x", "y")

Write-Host "$($array.GetType().Name)"
Write-Host "$($array.GetType().BaseType)"

$bad = {
    $array += "z"
    Write-Host "$($array.GetType().Name)"
    Write-Host "$($array.GetType().BaseType)"
    $array
}

$good = {
    $array = $array.Clone()
    $array += "z"
    Write-Host "$($array.GetType().Name)"
    Write-Host "$($array.GetType().BaseType)"
    $array
}

& $good
& $bad
```

Executing the script will produce the following output:

```
Object[]
array
Object[]
array
x
y
z
String
System.Object
z
```

The scriptblock `$bad` does not work as I would expect. It converts the array to string, but it should simply add the element `z` to the array. If there is no element added, the array can be used as expected.

I noticed this behaviour in powershell 5.0 and 5.1 but not in the ISE. Is it a bug or can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope issue. The variable on the left side of the assignment operation in the scriptblocks is defined in the local scope.

This statement

```
$array = $array.Clone()
```

clones the value of the *global* variable `$array` and assigns it to the *local* variable `$array` (same name, but different variable due to different scope). The local variable `$array` then contains a copy of the original array, so the next statement

```
$array += "z"
```

appends a new element to that array.

In your other scriptblock you immediately append a string to the (local) variable `$array`. In that context the local variable is empty, so `$array += "z"` has the same effect as `$array = "z"`, leaving you with a variable containing just the string "z".

Specify the correct scope and you'll get the behavior you expect:

```
$array = @("x", "y")

$not_bad = {
    $script:array += "z"
    Write-Host "$($script:array.GetType().Name)"
    Write-Host "$($script:array.GetType().BaseType)"
    $script:array
}

& $not_bad
```

Beware, however, that this will actually modify the original array in the global/script scope (your `$good` example leaves the original array unchanged).

I'm not sure if I would consider this behavior a bug, but it's definitely a gotcha.

Comment: Thanks. While your answer is right I realize that the script example may not archive the whole problem. The original script has different behaviour in console and ISE. The example script behaves equal.

Comment: ISE and console are different host processes that are known to behave differently in some respects. I'd suggest posting a new question with a updated code and problem description if that issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post my preferred solution which bases on Ansgars explanation:

```
$array = @("x", "y")

$not_bad = {
    $array = $array + "z"
    Write-Host "$($array.GetType().Name)"
    Write-Host "$($array.GetType().BaseType)"
    $array
}

& $not_bad
```

Important is the assignment to the local variable (or better to create a local variable) before adding further elements. A simple

```
$array = $array
```

would do, but this line may be confusing.

Comment: It is hard to believe that the different behaviour of `$a = $a + "z"` and `$a += "z"` was intention and not a bug.

Comment: `$a += "z"` isn't just syntactic sugar for `$a = $a + "z"`. It's semantic is actually slightly different The latter statement means "append 'z' to the variable on the right-hand side and assign the result to the variable on the left-hand side" whereas the former means "append 'z' to the variable on the left-hand side". They produce the same result when you're using the same variable on both sides of the assignment. However, in your particular scenario that is not the case (`$a` on the left-hand side is in the local scope, `$a` on the right-hand side is in the global scope).

Comment: You are totally right. But it makes code hard to understand (and to write). In `c++` one can code different behaviour for both operators `+` and `+=` but one should not, cause it is confusing.  In `PS` it is by design!?

Comment: The problem is not with the operators per se, but with the different evaluation of scopes on either side of the assignment. Like I said, it's definitely a gotcha. I don't know the reasons for the decision to make PowerShell (or the underlying .Net framework) evaluate things that way, though. Maybe @BrucePayette could shed some light.